# How to use Rails link_to to POST to the controller and have an HTML class attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've looked up the `link_to` in the Apidock but simply can't get the proper Rails syntax to create the following:

```
<a href="/benefits/create" class="btn btn-primary">All Changes Complete</a>
```

I have:

```
<%= link_to t('view.benefits.all_changes_complete'), { controller: "benefits", action: "create", method: :post }, { class: "btn btn-primary"} %>
```

The above syntax kind of works, but the `method: :post` is being added to the href and clicking the link does a GET, resulting in the following:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/benefits/create?method=post">All Changes Complete</a>
```

Comment: are you making a get request or a post request? If you are trying to make a post request then you should use a form and make the form look like a link with a submit button. Rails will add in a security token within that form to prevent cross site request forgery attacks - which you will be open to if you are trying to make a post request like that with just a simple link. I'm assuing you have not deleted the protect_from_forgery method in your application controller that is inserted with a standard rails application.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon - Thanks for the response, good question.  Actually I'm not really trying to support a form or data, just trying to add a RESTful route back to my controller to indicate the user has reviewed the information.  Should I be doing a GET to a named route then?  Was hoping to keep my controllers having just the index/show/update/create methods.  Doing a GET to a /create method seems weird - or is it?

Comment: have updated answer. using a GET request to create thing is a rails no-no. see below answer. hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry change it to post have updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try this.

Controller is `benefits` then if you run the command `rake routes` then it will be show looks like this

routes.rb

```
resources :benefits
```

---

```
Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
benefits GET    /benefits(.:format)          benefits#index
         POST   /benefits(.:format)          benefits#create
```

Create action is `benefits_path` when it going to `post` method than `link_to` will be

```
<%= link_to "All Changes Complete", benefits_path, method: :post,  class: "btn btn-primary"%>
```

It will generate HTML looks like

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/benefits" class="btn btn-primary">  All Changes Complete</a>
```

After clicking then it action looks like

```
POST   /benefits(.:format)          benefits#create
```

Then if you need send `parameters` then `link_to` looks like

```
<%= link_to "All Changes Complete", benefits_path(param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'), method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

It will generate looks like

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-method="post" href="/benefits?param1=value1&param2=value2" class="btn btn-primary">All Changes Complete</a>
```

For receiving parameters

```
params[:param1]
params[:param2]
```

That's it

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but what about the html 'class' attribute?  That's the one that I'm having trouble with, if I add it as a parameter to the link_to, it adds it to the url...

Comment: I have updated the answer just added `,class: "btn btn-primary"`

Comment: Is support for `data-method` to specify HTTP request method for `<a>` cross major browsers and frameworks? This solution does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

#### When to use get request

- Use the get request if you are not changing state. if you are basically displaying information.
- Do not use the get request to create records. It is not a standard rails practice. You will not be protected from cross site request forgery if you use a simple link which will create records from a get request.

#### When to use post

Use post if you are creating new records ( or changing records via patch).

- If you are not doing a get request then you'll basically need to use a form (however you solve the issue). Something like this:

`form_tag({:controller => "benefits", :action => "create"}, :method => "post", :class => "btn btn-primary")`

#### The purpose

- to indicate the user has reviewed the form? This sounds like a retrieval of information so you could use a get request via a named route.
- you could also use a helper method to supply the same information without using a named route.
- you could also use a check box on the original form that the user must tick to indicate that they have read the form etc prior to submitting the form.